# Is there any way to connect a new Wordpress site with a RoR web app and to manage its legacy database from the Wordpress site without data migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I currently have a Ruby on Rails web application and an existing database made by previous team project.

What I need to do is to migrate that website to Wordpress. I've developed something in Wordpress with the help of Custom Content Type plugin and it creates some custom posts correctly.

Now, the problem is how to migrate the database with all data to the other one with Wordpress structure.

Someone told me about the WP Rest API plugin for Wordpress, but I think that it won't work for me because it allows you to connect several websites only when all of them are Wordpress sites, or when one of them is a non Wordpress site, but in this last case you can manage this site from Wordpress and you could perform CRUD actions only in Wordpress site database but not in the other one, I think... or am I wrong?

Basically, I need to manage current database from the Wordpress site and to show all the information to the user.

Anyone can help me, please? Any idea would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very ambitious! Here's what I would do:

Create a rake task in the current ruby site that loops through every existing blog and create a new blog on the wordpress site through the Wordpress API.

It looks like there is a gem that could make this very easy. https://github.com/zachfeldman/rubypress

```
# Here is some pseudo code
# Make new api client
wordpress_api = Client.new 

ExistingPost.find_each do |blog_post|
  wordpress_api.post(blog_post details here)
end
```

I would avoid the database to database migration if I could because it would be more tedious.

Comment: Thanks @penner! I'm very sorry for taking so long time to respond :(. Currently I'm not able to get the RoR source code so it's impossible for me to create the task you have proposed but I've got data from the existing database instead. I had thought that I could create an application, for example in Django, to make the database migration but it would be very tedious to make it database to database. Any idea to make it a little bit easier?